# Make updates to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm pretty sure this is not the best thing to do - change/add/update Laravel core but I'm facing the following problem.

Version 7 has a new date serialization format ([more info here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization)) and I want to update it to the old return value. What they suggest to do is add this in each model.

```
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date) {
     return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

As I have numerous models I was wondering if I can do a more general thing and update the abstract Model Class for example. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As Eloquent model is not localized by default in your project. You should create a Model class and inherit from the eloquent model

```
namespace App\Models;

use DateTimeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;

/**
 * Class Model
 * @package App\Models
 * @method static count
 * @method static latest
 * @method static oldest
 */
class Model extends BaseModel
{
    /**
     * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
     *
     * @param DateTimeInterface $date
     * @return string
     */
    protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
    {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

Then, update all of the models to inherit from your local Model class, not the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Comment: I was also thinking of that but this also requires going through each model which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes, you should change that in all of your models because you should not change `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.